# Prism 7.1.0 Using app.config to load modules

Tags: prism, prism-6

I am trying to load views and viewmodels in a module using app.config and Prism 7.1.0.279-pre.  I cannot find any post anywhere that seems to get this to work.  Does anyone have any examples?

I have a basic understanding from MEF when it was early on.  I would like to be able to create apps with multiple reusable modules and would like to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`ConfigurationModuleCatalog`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Modularity/ConfigurationModuleCatalog.Desktop.cs).

Therefore, you need a `ModulesConfigurationSection` in your app.config named `modules`. This is where you define the modules to load.

An example is in the [documentation](https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/Modules.html#specify-dependencies-in-configuration).

BTW - Prism 7 has dropped support for MEF. Use a container like unity or dryioc for dependency injection and reserve MEF for plugin system.

Comment: Actually I am using Unity I just remember briefly taking a look at MEF when it was young (in the early 2ks :))  I tried that but could not figure out if I was doing something wrong.  I ended up adding the module to the catalog via AddModule.  Not as loosely coupled as I would have hoped as I had to have a reference to the module in my shell.

Comment: The app.config stuff is as straight forward as possible, just the fully qualified type names look a bit intimidating. Have a look at my edit.

Comment: I don't get it.  I have created the simplest app and module.  At what point in the process would I be able to see the Modules count > 0 in the catalog?

Comment: So turns out if I roll back to 6.30 with a bootstrapper it works.  7 doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: So 7 works but not using PrismApplication but instead Using 7 with UnityBootStrapper it seems to work.